# Update an asp:TextBox when a asp:ListBox changes selected item

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, listbox

I'm new to ASP.Net and I have the following doubt:
Is there a way to update the contents of a TextBox when the selected item of a ListBox is changed?
I have this:

```
<asp:ListBox ID="myListBox" runat="server" Width="200px"></asp:ListBox>
```

`<asp:TextBox ID="myTextBox" runat="server" Width="200" />`

The items on the ListBox are strings that are added in the Page_Load.
Basically, I want to put the selected item in the TextBox without having to make a PostBack and doing this in the code-behind (for eficiency).
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course. That's what client side programming is for (JavaScript).

When a `ListBox` is rendered to HTML by the server, it is converted to an HTML [select](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp) element. So you can use this code:

```
<asp:ListBox ID="myListBox" runat="server" Width="200px"></asp:ListBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="myTextBox" runat="server" Width="200" />

<!-- Below we're adding the reference to jQuery, which is publicly hosted on a CDN -->
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>

<!-- Here's where our JavaScript is -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('#<%=myListBox.ClientID %>').change(function(){ //when the select value of the list box changes, we're going to call the below code
        $('#<%=myTextBox.ClientID %>').val($('#<%=myListBox.ClientID %>').val()); // Set the value of the text box to the value of the list box.
    });
});
</script>
```

Note that I'm using the [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) library, a very popular JavaScript framework that makes client  side coding easier.

Note I'm using special syntax to embed the `ClientID` of the `ListBox` and `TextBox` into the JavaScript. That's because the JavaScript runs on the client side, and the ID of the `ListBox` and `TextBox` can change from the server to the client side based on the `ClientIDMode` (which is something that trips up a lot of Web Forms developers) that the control has specified. Embedding the `ClientID` ensure that the ID uses in the JavaScript on the client matches the ID of the select element on the client.